# sed command string variable concatenation within single quotes

Tags: linux, sed, concatenation

I want to modify the include_path directive in my php.ini file using sed. Below, I've got a command that looks for a string and places the directive on a line after the match. However, I cannot get it to work while still maintaining the double quotes within the ${install_path} variable. The double quotes must be there.

The file I want to edit is php.ini. Here are a few lines before and after my target, which is the line right after "UNIX: ":

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = "/path1:/path2"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
```

install_path is defined as:

```
install_path="/var/www/mainapp"
```

And the sed command I am using below searches for a string match and then creates a new line right below it:

```
sed -i '/; UNIX: "\/path1:\/path2"/a include_path = "${install_path}/lib"' /etc/php.ini
```

The expected output within php.ini is:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = "/var/www/mainapp/lib"
```

Where the include_path line has been created right after the line "; UNIX:..."

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edit your question to include some testable sample input and expected output. Also show us how you are populating the `install_path` variable.

Comment: I've edited it to have the install_path definition and expected results. Thanks.

Comment: showing the output is half of what we need - show the input too. Also, show a few lines of context around the line(s) you want changed as it's always trivial to change the parts you want changed but MUCH harder to not change other parts that you don't want changed.

Comment: I've added the definition for install_path variable. That really is the only input going into the sed command.

Comment: no that's just a variable you want the script to use to help transform the input to the output. The input is the contents of file `php.ini` before you run your script on it. You don't have to show the whole file, just the line you want to find and a couple of lines before/after it so we have something we can test a potential solution against to make sure it produces exactly the output you say it should (so make sure your expected output also includes the unchanged context lines if that's what you want).

Comment: Got it. i've included some lines before and after my target, which is the currently commented out ;include_path = "/path1:/path2" right after the UNIX: line.

Comment: OK, so now you've posted sample input, edit your question again so that the expected output is EXACTLY what you want that sample input changed into by your script. In particular show us if you want that commented out line to remain after the new line we're adding or do you want the new line to replace that commented out line. Just imagine you are creating a test case for your problem as that IS exactly what you're doing by providing us sample input+output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is dancing around the quoting conventions of the shell while preserving the quotes in the file.

You say you've defined `install_path="/var/www/mainapp"`; note that the quotes were removed by the shell so the string contains no quotes.  That's important below.  Compare the old and the new:

Old:

```
sed -i '/; UNIX: "\/path1:\/path2"/a include_path = "${install_path}/lib"' /etc/php.ini
```

New:

```
sed -i '/; UNIX: "\/path1:\/path2"/a include_path = "'"${install_path}/lib"'"' /etc/php.ini
```

Eh what?  You've correctly enclosed your script in single quotes, but that prevents the shell from expanding `${install_path}`.  So, you have to terminate the single-quoted string, but you want double quotes in the output, so I placed the single quote after the double quote.  Then I wrapped the value in `${install_path}` in double quotes too: `"${install_path}/lib"`.  The double quotes are not crucial for the value you quote, but in general it is a good idea to use them.  I then  resume the single-quoting, and the first character is the closing double quote for the include path string in the `.ini` file, and then close the single quoted string.  Yes, there are other ways you could write that last bit, but it would take considerable persuasion to convince me that alternatives using backslashes are better.

If you actually had preserved the double quotes around the install path value:

```
install_path='"/var/www/mainapp"'
```

you could use:

```
sed -i '/; UNIX: "\/path1:\/path2"/a include_path = '"${install_path}/lib" /etc/php.ini
```

Also note that only GNU `sed` allows you to put 'appended text' on the same line as the `a` command.  POSIX `sed` does not, and other variants of `sed` on other platforms will not.  For instance, on Mac OS X, you'd have to write:

```
sed -i '/; UNIX: "\/path1:\/path2"/a\
include_path = '"${install_path}/lib" /etc/php.ini
```

Comment: Amazing detailed information! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much - I was not as familiar with the quote conventions in bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything even slightly more interesting you should be using awk. Chances are you want something like this:

```
awk -v install_path="$install_path" '
{ print }
/; UNIX: "\/path1:\/path2"/ { printf "include_path = \"%s/lib\"\n", install_path }
' /etc/php.ini
```

but without sample input and expected output it's a guess. To replace the contents of the original file just add `> tmp && mv tmp /etc/php.ini` to the end or use `-i inplace` up front with GNU awk.

Comment: I've edited my question to include input and output. Thanks!

Comment: You've included output so far but still haven't shown us the input that produces that output. I expect this script will do what you want anyway though.

Comment: Thanks for you time and help. @Jonathan Leffler answer maintained the use of sed and worked great. I was just missing quotation conventions used in bash scripts.

Comment: You're welcome but again, this is NOT a job for sed. Using sed for anything other than simple substitutions on individual lines is like planting trees with a teaspoon. Yeah you can do it, but at some point you're going to want to pick up a shovel...